# Select/Deselect options in one multiselect field based on selection from another multiselect

Tags: jquery, html, multi-select, jquery-1.9

I have the following HTML with me containing various multiselect boxes -

```
 <p>
 <label>Main Category</label>
 <select id="mainSelect" name="super_category" multiple>
    <option value="CatA">CatA</option>
    <option value="CatB">CatB</option>
 </select>
 </p>
 <p>
 <label>SubCategoryA</label>
 <select class="multiselectbox" name="super_subcategory_CatA" multiple>
     <option value="SubcatA1">SubcatA1</option>
     <option value="SubcatA2">SubcatA2</option>
 </select>
 </p>
<p>
<label>SubCategoryB</label>
<select class="multiselectbox" name="contact_subcategory_CatB" multiple>
     <option value="SubcatB1">SubcatB1</option>
     <option value="SubcatB2">SubcatB2</option>
</select>
</p>
```

I am trying to create dynamic jquery code where in if i select any option from `subcategory_X` multiselect field that same sub category should get selected in `super_category` multiselect

Similarly when I deselect any option subcategory_X from `super_category` multiselect, any/all options from the particular `subcategory_X` s multiselect should get deselected.

Trying to do this using Jquery but I'm a newbie to it. Was thinking of doing this on `onchange` event such that if any option is selected/deselected from any multi-select, it's corresponding "category" either gets selected in the "super_category" multiselect or all values get deselected from "subcategory"'s own multiselect.

Hope I haven't confused any one. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: JSfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/M53JX/

Comment: When you have a problem like this, try to begin in coding a fiddle (jsfiddle.net per exemple), and send the link. With that, you show that you try something, and after, it will be faster for men who canhelp you to answer you.

Comment: Yes sorry about that. I have actually tried the above in jsfiddle but forgot to add my jsfiddle link. Will edit the ques now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mainSelect').on('change', function () {
        $("select[name^=contact_subcategory] option").prop("selected", "");
        var name = $(this).val(); alert(name);
        $(name).each(function() {
            $("select[name=contact_subcategory_" +this  + "] option").prop("selected", "selected"); 
        })

    });
});
```

[***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/M53JX/1/)

Comment: Thanks !! I needed to do it the other way round, ie on selection of SubCatA1, or SubCatB1, select CatA1, CatB1 in main multiselect. But this gives me an idea and can clearly revert your logic. So Thanks again for providing this.